# How do i get a Request Object outside a controller in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

Is there a way to get the Request Object in a Html Helper Method.

I'd like to know if a file exists to replace non existent Files with a default Image.
Therefore i need the Request Object and it's Method MapPath(path).

Has anybody an idea.

Thx Thomas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request`

Comment: shouldn't be using a win forms call which is what that is.  You should be using HttpRequestBase for MVC apps or else you're polluting your MVC app with non-MVC code.